# How to use JSON queries with Haystack using Elasticsearch?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I would like to use following JSON query with Haystack, but cannot find how to use JSON queries instead of QuerySet (as it seems there is no way to do this in QuerySet).

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists" : { 
                    "field" : "category_featured"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an alternative for that query in QuerySet.

For 'exists' filter it is possible to use this:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(_exists_='category_featured')
```

For 'missing' filter this:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(_missing_='category_featured')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about JSON, not everything has an alternative (for example advanced more_like_this queries suck in haystack)